# how to pad text sequences in R using keras and pad_sequences?

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras

I have a dataset with texts.

```
dat <- data.frame(id=c("1","2","3","4","5"),text=as.character(c("hello","hello you","hello duck","Dogs and cats","hello cats, ducks and dogs")),stringsAsFactors = F)
str(dat)
```

and I would like to prepare the text for text classification with keras. This works well with a low number of tokens and padding.

```
library(keras)
install_keras()
library(dplyr)

data<- dat$text

tok <- keras::text_tokenizer(10, lower = TRUE, split = " ", char_level
= FALSE) keras::fit_text_tokenizer(tok, data) data_idx <- keras::texts_to_sequences(tok, data)


data_idx <- data_idx %>% pad_sequences(maxlen=10,padding="post",value=0)

> data_idx
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[2,]    1    5    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[3,]    1    6    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[4,]    2    3    4    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[5,]    1    4    7    3    2    0    0    0    0     0
```

However, if I raise the number of token and padding (which I have to for my real texts), I get a strange padded sequence.

```
data<- dat$text

tok <- keras::text_tokenizer(10000, lower = TRUE, split = " ", char_level = FALSE)
keras::fit_text_tokenizer(tok, data)
data_idx <- keras::texts_to_sequences(tok, data)


data_idx <- data_idx %>% pad_sequences(maxlen=10000,padding="post",value=0)

> data_idx
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15] [,16] [,17] [,18] [,19] [,20] [,21] [,22] [,23] [,24] [,25]
     [,26] [,27] [,28] [,29] [,30] [,31] [,32] [,33] [,34] [,35] [,36] [,37] [,38] [,39] [,40] [,41] [,42] [,43] [,44] [,45] [,46] [,47] [,48] [,49]
     [,50] [,51] [,52] [,53] [,54] [,55] [,56] [,57] [,58] [,59] [,60] [,61] [,62] [,63] [,64] [,65] [,66] [,67] [,68] [,69] [,70] [,71] [,72] [,73]
     [,74] [,75] [,76] [,77] [,78] [,79] [,80] [,81] [,82] [,83] [,84] [,85] [,86] [,87] [,88] [,89] [,90] [,91] [,92] [,93] [,94] [,95] [,96] [,97]
     [,98] [,99] [,100] [,101] [,102] [,103] [,104] [,105] [,106] [,107] [,108] [,109] [,110] [,111] [,112] [,113] [,114] [,115] [,116] [,117] [,118]
     [,119] [,120] [,121] [,122] [,123] [,124] [,125] [,126] [,127] [,128] [,129] [,130] [,131] [,132] [,133] [,134] [,135] [,136] [,137] [,138]
     [,139] [,140] [,141] [,142] [,143] [,144] [,145] [,146] [,147] [,148] [,149] [,150] [,151] [,152] [,153] [,154] [,155] [,156] [,157] [,158]
     [,159] [,160] [,161] [,162] [,163] [,164] [,165] [,166] [,167] [,168] [,169] [,170] [,171] [,172] [,173] [,174] [,175] [,176] [,177] [,178]
     [,179] [,180] [,181] [,182] [,183] [,184] [,185] [,186] [,187] [,188] [,189] [,190] [,191] [,192] [,193] [,194] [,195] [,196] [,197] [,198]
     [,199] [,200] [,201] [,202] [,203] [,204] [,205] [,206] [,207] [,208] [,209] [,210] [,211] [,212] [,213] [,214] [,215] [,216] [,217] [,218]
```

I think I got something totally wrong, but I cannot solve it.

Comment: Check the structure of `data_idx` i..e. `str(data_idx)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong in the output.  We need to check the dimension

```
dim(data_idx)
#[1]     5 10000
```

It is just that the console is printing only the column header and based on the `max.print`it couldn't show the whole output

```
#[ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 5 rows ]
```

If we subset, the output can be seen

```
data_idx[1:3, 1:3]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    0    0
#[2,]    1    5    0
#[3,]    1    6    0
```